# What are Extension Methods?

Tags: .net, extension-methods

What are extension methods in .NET?

EDIT:
I have posted a follow up question at [Usage of Extension Methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403619/usage-of-extension-methods)

Comment: For your followup, see my answer below.

Basically you would create extensions instead of using inheritance.

Comment: @Tom Anderson - So the decision to create extension methods is mostly based on access to source?

Comment: in my case, yes.

Another instance is ease, instead of inheriting from System.Windows.Forms.Form and adding the method and then modifying all of my source to use that base class, I simply write the extension and all forms have it now.

Comment: Try looking at this question as well.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371272/c-extension-methods-how-far-is-too-far

Comment: Here is concise article on Extension Methods in c# with enough information to get you started: [How and when to use Extension Methods in C# and .Net](http://aspdotnetfaq.com/Faq/How-and-when-to-use-Extension-Methods-in-Csharp-and-dot-NET.aspx)

Comment: https://www.codingcrest.com/extension-method-in-c/

Answer (score 69, accepted):

> **Extension methods** allow developers to add new methods to the public
>   contract of an existing CLR type,
>   without having to sub-class it or
>   recompile the original type.
>
> Extension Methods help blend the
>   flexibility of "duck typing" support
>   popular within dynamic languages today
>   with the performance and compile-time
>   validation of strongly-typed
>   languages.

*Reference: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/03/13/new-orcas-language-feature-extension-methods.aspx*

Here is a sample of an Extension Method (notice the `this` keyword infront of  the first parameter):

```
public static bool IsValidEmailAddress(this string s)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$");
    return regex.IsMatch(s);
}
```

Now, the above method can be called directly from any string, like such:

```
bool isValid = "so@mmas.com".IsValidEmailAddress();
```

The added methods will then also appear in IntelliSense:

[image]
<sub>(source: [scottgu.com](http://www.scottgu.com/blogposts/extensionmethods/step1.jpg))</sub>

As regards a practical use for Extension Methods, you might add new methods to a class without deriving a new class.

Take a look at the following example:

```
public class Extended {
    public int Sum() {
        return 7+3+2;
    }
}

public static class Extending {
    public static float Average(this Extended extnd) {
        return extnd.Sum() / 3;
    }
}
```

As you see, the class `Extending` is adding a method named average to class `Extended`. To get the average, you call `average` method, as it belongs to `extended` class:

```
Extended ex = new Extended();

Console.WriteLine(ex.average());
```

*Reference: http://aspguy.wordpress.com/2008/07/03/a-practical-use-of-serialization-and-extension-methods-in-c-30/*

Comment: 100% correct, although I have a beef with adding extension methods to primitive types such as string that aren't Fundamental to the type.  Thus, I wouldn't add 'IsValidEmailAddress' to string, but I have added Left(int) and Right(int).

Answer (score 14):

### Extension Methods - Simple Explanation

You can add methods to something, even though you don't have access to the original source code. Let's consider an example to explain that point:

#### Example:

Suppose I have a dog. All dogs – all animals of type dog - do certain things:

1. Eat
2. WagsTail
3. Cries “Woof / Bow / Wang!” etc

The things that a dog can do are all called “methods”. Now let’s suppose the Great Programmer in OO Heaven forgot to add a method to the dog class: FetchNewspaper(). You want to be able to say:

```
rex.FetchNewspaper(); // or
beethoven.FetchNewspaper();
```

......even though you *don't* have access to the source code.

**How are you doing to get your dog to do that?** Your only solution is to to create an “extension method”.

### Creating an Extension Method

(Note the “this” keyword in front of the first parameter below):

```
public static void FetchNewsPaper(this Dog familyDog)
{
     Console.Writeline(“Goes to get newspaper!”)
}
```

And if you want your dog to get the newspaper simply do this:

```
Dog freddie_the_family_dog = new Dog();

freddie_the_family_dog.FetchNewspaper();
```

You can add a method onto a class *without having the source code*. This can be extremely handy!

Answer (score 5):

Extension methods are ways for developers to "add on" methods to objects they can't control.

For instance, if you wanted to add a "DoSomething()" method to the System.Windows.Forms object, since you don't have access to that code, you would simply create an extension method for the form with the following syntax.

```
Public Module MyExtensions

    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
    Public Sub DoSomething(ByVal source As System.Windows.Forms.Form)
        'Do Something
    End Sub

End Module
```

Now within a form you can call "Me.DoSomething()".

In summary, it is a way to add functionality to existing objects without inheritance.

Answer (score 5):

An extension method is a "compiler trick" that allows you to simulate the addition of methods to another class, even if you do not have the source code for it.

For example:

```
using System.Collections;
public static class TypeExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a value that indicates whether or not the collection is empty.
    /// </summary>
    public static bool IsEmpty(this CollectionBase item)
    {
        return item.Count == 0;
    } 
}
```

In theory, all collection classes now include an `IsEmpty` method that returns true if the method has no items (provided that you've included the namespace that defines the class above).

If I've missed anything important, I'm sure someone will point it out. (Please!)

Naturally, there are rules about the declaration of extension methods (they must be static, the first parameter must be preceeded by the `this` keyword, and so on).

Extension methods do not actually modify the classes they appear to be extending; instead, the compiler mangles the function call to properly invoke the method at run-time. However, the extension methods properly appear in intellisense dropdowns with a distinctive icon, and you can document them just like you would a normal method (as shown above).

**Note:** An extension method *never* replaces a method if a method already exists with the same signature.

Comment: Best explanation. Thanks Mike.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the example in VB.Net; notice the Extension() attribute. Place this in a Module in your project.

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices
<Extension()> _
Public Function IsValidEmailAddress(ByVal s As String) As Boolean
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(s) Then Return False

    Return Regex.IsMatch(email, _
         "^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$")
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Extension method is the technique thru which we can add method to existing data type. Below is the example how we can add methods to existing data type.

1. We have created an extension method class in which we have created various  extension methods

Code:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static int WordCount(this string str)
    {
        return str.Split(' ').Count();
    }

    public static int LongestWord(this string str)
    {
        return str.Split(' ').Select(x =>
                x.Length).OrderByDescending(y =>
                y).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

2. Below is the program class where we have called extension methods specified in above class.

Code:

```
public static void Main(String[] args)
{
    string str = "this is my name    punit";
    int i = str.LongestWord();
}
```

Key points:

- extension method class need to be static
- extension method's first argument will have this keyword and that method should also be static

Answer (score 1):

Extension methods are special kind of static methods. It allows us to add method in existing type without modifying that existing type.
E.g. If you have Customer class and you need to add one more method in it without modification in Customer class, For such scenarios we have extension methods.
refer this link for more examples 
https://princesid85.wixsite.com/website/home/you-ve-been-holding-your-pen-wrong-your-entire-life

Answer (score 0):

This question has already been answered, but I'd like to add that it is very useful if you've got types that are within another project and you don't want to go back to that project in order to add some functionality. We're using NHibernate and have a project for our data persistence layer that the guys want to keep clean. In order to get nice and discoverable additional methods onto those object I was able to use extension methods and it really brightened my day.

Also, since no one else has posted it, here's a good article about it on MSDN - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'll add an explanation which is more conceptual and less reliant on code.

Imagine a Ford rolling off the construction line. You don't have access to the construction line, but you want all Ford cars to be able to have an additional spoiler added to the back of the car (looks cooler when on display). How are you gonna do that? In the world of computing, unless you have access to the original construction line inside a Ford factory, you can't just go about bolting things to the Ford. Well now you can: ENTER extension methods.

Now you can do things like this:

```
Ford hilux = new Ford();

hilux.DisplayRearFoiler(); // you can now do this even though you don't have access to the Ford source code.
```

You'll have to create the extension method. Refer to the above answers.

Answer (score 0):

I want to answer the Extension Methods in terms of a **Sealed class**.

Suppose you have a **Sealed Class** that contains vital methods. You now want to add a new method to it. Suppose this class comes in an external DLL so you cannot add a new method to it. What you will do ?

Take another example. Suppose that class is built in your application by your Project Manager or Security Guru. You can edit that class only by taking the permission of your Project Manager or Security Guru.

> You solution may be to remove the Sealed Keyword from this class and
>   inherit it in other class. Then inside the sub-class (that inherits this class) you can add your new method.

But Wait -> You cannot simply remove the Sealed Keyword as this can compromise the security of the whole application.  I can bet you that your PM or Security Guru will never give you that permission citing security issues.

So what can be done in here?

The Answer is **Extension Methods** which can be added in a static class and you don't even need to touch the sealed class anymore.

**Example:-**

```
sealed class MyData
{
    private double D1, D2, D3;
    public MyData(double d1, double d2, double d3)
    { D1 = d1; D2 = d2; D3 = d3; }
    public double Sum() { return D1 + D2 + D3; }
}

static class ExtendMyData
{
    public static double Average(this MyData md)
    {
        return md.Sum() / 3;
    }
}
```

I have added a public static method named **Average** to a new static class. This method has the parameter of the main class with 'this' keyword in front.

Now to call the Average method I use the object of the parent sealed class and not the sub-class.

```
 MyData md = new MyData(3, 4, 5);
 double exAverage = md.Average();
```

Hope you find Extension Methods useful.

Answer (score 0):

**Extension Method in C#**

What is extension method?

```
Extension method means Class name and method name are having with Static Key word.
```

Extension method using “this” keyword and Should be first signature is mention identify address, this type is must same for like,

public static string Meth(**this string** i,int j)

and

string res = **"ae"**.Meth(num);

The Bold part is identification address. The Namespace should be same.

**Why we need Extension?**

We are using same function in to many places, after could not find why we use here. For this reason using address identification. Static means single instance. This can only access static member function. Even how do access without static class methods in Static class? Ex : see throwing Error in “Sal” method,

static class Emp
    {
        public int Sal(int i,int j)
        {
            return i * j;
        }
    }

Access only static member. And

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAQjK.jpg)

The following that code we could not create object for non-static class with in static class. Then how to access non-static method into static class. For this reason, we are follow Extension method without inheritance.

For Example, Add or Even functionality using Extension method here,

using System. Text;

using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Extension_Method
{
    static class Program
    {

```
    public static string Meth (this string i,int j)
    {
        if (j % 2 == 0)
        {
            return "Even";
        }
        else
        {
            return "ODD";

        }
    }


}
class program2
{
    static void Main (string [] args)
    {
        Console. WriteLine ("Enter Integer");
        int num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        string res = "ae".Meth(num);

        Console. WriteLine(res);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxYSC.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes we want to add our own additional functionalities to a type and use them as usual instance methods on that type. If we would have the source code, we could easily add new functionality without creating extension methods. But problem occurs when we do not have source code & still want to add and call additional functionality as instance methods on a type; extension methods serve this purpose of adding our own functionalities to a type & use them as instance methods on the type when source code is unavailable.

When we want to add our own functionality, we can even **create a separate static class** and call its static methods in our code instead of creating extension methods, but problem with that can be **code readability**.

**LINQ** benefits greatly from extension methods.

They can be really helpful at the time of Development, when the required methods are easily available using Intellisense to multiple developers; while with static methods we would have to write *className.MethodName()* every time in our code.

Comment: Thanks for your good answer. The question you've answered is almost 10 years old, and already have accepted answers. To make sure you gather the upvotes you deserve, consider including what differentiates this answer from the others.

Answer (score 0):

```
/// <summary>
/// External Library Code
/// </summary>
namespace ExternalLibrary
{
    public class Calculator
    {
        public int Number1 { get; set; }
        public int Number2 { get; set; }

        public int Addition()
        {
            return Number1 + Number2;
        }

        public int Subtraction()
        {
            return Number1 - Number2;
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
using ExternalLibrary;
using System;

namespace StackOverFlow
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Calculator calc = new Calculator()
            {
                Number1 = 5,
                Number2 = 3
            };
            Console.WriteLine(calc.Addition());
            Console.WriteLine(calc.Subtraction());

            // Here we want multiplication also. but we don't have access Calculator
            // class code, so we can't modify in that.
            // In order to achieve this functionality we can use extension method.
            Console.WriteLine(calc.Multiplication());

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Extension Method for multiplication
    /// </summary>
    public static class CalculatorExtension
    {
        public static int Multiplication(this Calculator calc)
        {
            return calc.Number1 * calc.Number2;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Code examples are always a good answer. But the quality of the answer is drastically improved when there is supporting commentary on how that code improves/fixes the issue.