# Converted project .net 2.0 to 3.5, where are the extension methods?

Tags: .net-3.5, .net-2.0, project

I've recently converted an app from .net 2.0 to 3.5 but I don't see any extension methods... what am I doing wrong? Or what else should I do besides changing the target framework from 2.0 to 3.5 in project settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extension methods appear based on the imported namespaces try adding

```
using System.Linq;
```

to the top of your files. As Jon says you'll also need add a reference to System.Core.dll assembly.

Answer (score 1):

You not only need to add the using directive for `System.Linq` as SillyMonkey suggested, but you also need to have a reference to the `System.Core` assembly if you want to use LINQ.

Comment: @argh - I think it is. But it makes for a more complete answer (eg. the reference may get left out depending on how the project is upgraded)

Answer (score 0):

Extension method, is feature of .net 3.5. extension methods are some thing that you need to create !!!

[What are Extension Methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403539/what-are-extension-methods)

refer this link

Comment: actually there are bunch of default extensions ships with 3.5.

Comment: dude, I don't know if you know... but there are extension methods ALREADY written in 3.5

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood you question!! my fault :)