# Can someone explain what Extension Methods are in C# and how the work

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are Extension Methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403539/what-are-extension-methods)

Can someone explain what Extension Methods are in C# and how the work in layman's terms and if possible some examples please

Comment: please read learning material (books, tutorials) and search the web.

Comment: Deniis, this site is for concrete questions, not for piecemeal education.

Answer (score 1):

Extension methods are syntactic sugar for static method calls.

The following are equivalent:

Extension:

```
public static int GetLength(this string s)
{
    return s.Length;
}

s.GetLength();
```

Static:

```
public static int GetLength(string s)
{
  return s.Length;
}

SomeClass.GetLength(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

In summary, Extension Method is syntax sugar, allowing to create a method in fact not belonging to type. Indeed, that's just a static method threated by compiler as a member "native".

Assuming you have a type:

```
class Test
{
    void Foo();
}
```

Let's declare an extension method:

```
static class Extensions
{
    public void Bar(this Foo) { }
}
```

Now you can call it:

```
new Test().Foo(); // "native" method
new Test().Bar(); // extension method
```

In fact that's just this:

```
public static void Bar(Test t) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can already find enough references on this topic on the web, like this MSDN [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx).

In a nutshell, extension methods allow you to extend a class without deriving it. They are some particular static methods, belonging to a static class. They always start with a parameter of the type they extend, prefixed with the keyword this. Let's say you want a method to return the extension of a file from a string (hope the logic is right, didn't check it actually):

```
public static class FileExtension
{
    public static string Extension(this string filename)
    {
        int index = filename.LastIndexOf('.');
        if(index > 0)
            return filename.Substring(index, filename.length - index);

        return filename;
    }
}
```

And then you can say:

```
string filename = "c:\temp\sample.txt";
string ext = filename.Extension();
```