# How do I extend the String class?

Tags: c#, extending-classes

Extending core classes in javascript is dead easy. I get the impression it's not quite so easy in C#. I was wanting to add some things to the String class so that I could do stuff like:

```
string s = "the cat's mat sat";
string sql = s.smartsingleQuote();
```

thus giving me

```
the cat''s mat sat
```

Is that even feasible, or do I have to write a function for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can do this, with an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx). It'll look something like that:

```
public static class NameDoesNotMatter {
   public static string smartSingleQuote(this string s) {
      string result = s.Replace("'","''");
      return result;
   } 
}
```

The magic is the keyword "this" in front of the first argument. Then you can write your code and it'll work:

```
string s = "the cat's mat sat";
string sql = s.smartsingleQuote();
```

Answer (score 12):

Yes it is possible using Extension Methods - [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx)

Here is a sample code.

```
public static class Extns
{
    public static string smartsingleQuote(this string s)
    {
        return s.Replace("'","''");
    }
}
```

Disclaimer : Not tested.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot accomplish exactly what you are talking about as the [string class is `sealed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx)

You can accomplish the aesthetic of this by creating an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx)

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
  public static string SmartSingleQuote(this string str)
  {
    //Do stuff here
  }
}
```

The `this` keyword in the parameter allows you to take that parameter and put it in front of the method name for easier chaining like you requested done in your question. This, however, is equivalent to:

```
StringExtensions.SmartSingleQuote(s);
```

It just depends on your preference at that point :)

[Here is a good SO answer on extension methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403539/what-are-extension-methods)

Comment: If you are using extension method, you can directly call s.SmartSingleQuote() right? If you are using StringExtensions.SmartSingleQuote(s), you don't require an extension method right?

Comment: @Anuraj yes, I did not re-hash that as that was part of the OP's question, which was already answered. I was trying to give a deeper understanding of extension methods to understand what it is equivalent to