# Difference between static and singleton classes c# OOPS

Tags: c#, .net, oop, singleton

I was searching for the difference between singleton & static classes, and I found many differences in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519520/difference-between-static-class-and-singleton-pattern). However, a few of them are not very clear to me:

> […] a singleton can extend classes and implement interfaces, while a static class cannot 
>   (it can extend classes, but it does not inherit their instance members). [[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519520/difference-between-static-class-and-singleton-pattern/519556#519556) by [neil.johnson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/58770/neil-johnson)]

> [Singletons have the] ability to return derived type (as a combination of lazyloading and interface implementation) [[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519520/difference-between-static-class-and-singleton-pattern/10502667#10502667) by [Tilak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/649524/tilak)]

What do these two points mean?

A few guys said they use singleton design pattern for their database connection, so that only one connection exist in the whole application and that this single connection is usedfor all requests. Can a single connection handle multiple database related request?

Please guide me if we should follow the singleton pattern for db connection handling. If not then please write all the pros & cons. thanks

Comment: When quoting answers by others, please make sure to actually quote them and *provide proper attribution*. Also, why even quote that many answers, when your question is just about *two* single points?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1. Singletons are first-and-foremost *objects*. As such, all the inheritance stuff applies to them as well. Static classes on the other hand are just containers for static functions (and static state). As static members will *not* be inherited when subtyping types, they do not benefit from inheritance at all. Interfaces also do not allow specifying static members, so you cannot use them either for static classes.
2. “Ability to return derived types” is a direct implication of the fact that singletons are objects. As objects, you can pass them to or return them from methods. This means that methods working with those singleton objects do not actually need to know that they are using singletons. Adding to that, you can use an interface type instead of the concrete singleton type. This allows for loose coupling, and makes the code more robust in general, as you can easily exchange that singleton object by some other object which provides the same functionality (by implementing the interface). So this is a good way to get rid of singletons in the long run and use things like [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) as a form of [inversion of control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control).

As for database connections, using singletons to maintain a permanent connection that is reused everywhere does make some kind of sense. However, there is usually a different approach in the .NET framework: That approach involves short-living connections that are only used for the very specific short duration a database connection is actually required. So instead of keeping the connection alive all the time, you create the connection, perform your query, and immediately close the connection.

Of course, permanently opening and closing database connections involves some drawback. To compensate that, the .NET frameworks uses a pooling strategy which keeps a number of connections around to be “created” quickly with a very small overhead. So instead of actually creating a real connection from scratch, you get an existing connection from the connection pool, work with it, and then release it back to the connection pool.

```
// create a new connection
using (var connection = new SqlConnection())
{
     // work with the connection
     doSomethingWith(connection);
}
// connection is now automatically closed and returned to the connection pool
```

Comment: u said : As static members will not be inherited when subtyping types
they do not benefit from inheritance at all

what does it mean ?

static class can extend another normal class or static class ?

what is not exposed to other class when they extend static class ?

when actually we should use static class...give some situation.

Comment: i am curious to know that when we go for in-built connection pooling then who create & maintain the connection pool. is it managed by OS or sql server or dotnet runtime ?

Comment: @Mou Well, as I said: Static classes can extend other types, but static members will not be inherited (see also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/774181/why-cant-i-inherit-static-classes)), they always stay *only* in the class they were declared in. So it just doesn’t work. As for when to use static classes, it depends. A very common usage is for [extension methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/403539/what-are-extension-methods). Other uses are for functions that simply don’t have any state (e.g. [System.Math](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.aspx)).

Comment: @Mou The connection pool is managed completely by the .NET framework. You usually don’t need to worry about it.

Comment: u said :- Static classes can extend other types, but static members will not be inherited. so what will be use if static class extend any normal class.

Comment: @Thomas Purely static classes don’t get any benefit from inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a singleton for database connections. Probably don't use singletons at all, they are heavily overused, provide very little benefit and cause trouble on their own. If you really want to use a singleton don't bother making it lazy because that is difficult and buys you even less. Using dependency injection is usually a much better way to solve the problem.

If you use Microsoft SQL Server .NET manages a connection pool for you [1] and there is usually no good reason you have to care about the details of creating, destroying and reusing connections to the server.

Microsoft SQL Server 2005 and later support Multiple Active Result Sets (MARS) [2] and so you are indeed able to run several queries using the same connection.

Things will obviously look different for other databases. I can elaborate on specific questions but the whole thing about static classes, singletons, resource locators and dependency injection is just to broad to be dealt with in one answer.

[1] http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx

[2] http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cfa084cz.aspx

Comment: i am curious to know that when we go for in-built connection pooling then who create & maintain the connection pool. is it managed by OS or sql server or dotnet runtime ?

Comment: From your perspective the connection pool is maintained by the .NET SQL Server library. Because connecting to a SQL Server including authentication is somewhat expensive the connection is not really closed when you call `Close` on the connection but the underlying connection is returned to the connection pool for later reuse. There is essentially one connection pool per connection string so that you get a connection matching what you requested. I am not sure if all is done in the library or if the library relies on some kind of native driver but you should not have to care.

Comment: I can only imagine that you might want to manage connections yourself and probably use MARS when you need hundreds and thousands of concurrent connections. But you will probably run into all kind of other problems when getting there and a redesign is probably the thing you should do. So for all practical purpose you never want to manage connections yourself.

Comment: You can specify the minimum and maximum pool size with the connection string and the maximum defaults to 100.