# Where can I find documentation for DbSet.toList()?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696460%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) in docs of `DbSet(TEntity)` I did not find `toList()`. Why is that so although this method works when invoked on `DbSet<TEntity>` as instance method. Related code I found is:

Part of controller:

```
private MovieDBContext db = new MovieDBContext();

        // GET: /Movie/
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Movies.ToList());
        }
```

DbContext class:

```
public class MovieDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: You can use toList() on anything that returns iQueryable and iEnumerable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are Extension Methods?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/403539/what-are-extension-methods)

Comment: @ZachM. There is no `ToList` overload for `IQueryable<T>`.  There is only one for `IEnumerable<T>`.  `IQueryable` extends `IEnumerable`.

Comment: You can always right-click a member and click "Go to Definition" to see where it originates. You'll then see in what namespace the member is defined and from which assembly it is loaded (or go straight to the source file if it's in your project).

Comment: Thank you, I was speaking generally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DbSet implements [IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.110).aspx).  [ToList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261(v=vs.110).aspx) is an extension method available on any IEnumerable from the [System.Linq.Enumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

Within the IDE, you can tell something is an extension method by the icon and the fact that the first parameter uses the `this` keyword.

[image: IDE screenshot]