# Getting data out of a Dictionary<string,object>

Tags: c#, json, object, dictionary

I use .NET to cast the JSON string into a Dictionary via the System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer type in the 3.5 System.Web.Extensions assembly.

I keep JSON data in a dictionary object, looks like:

```
        // Simple POST request
        using (System.Net.WebClient wb = new System.Net.WebClient())
        {
            // Random user data API - http://randomuser.me/
            string url = "http://api.randomuser.me/";

            var data = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();
            var responseStringJson = Encoding.Default.GetString(wb.UploadValues(url, "POST", data));

            var jsSerializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
            Dictionary<string, object> Results = jsSerializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(responseStringJson);
        }
```

**JSON Data Example**

```
{
  results: [{
    user: {
      gender: "male",
      name: {
        title: "mr",
        first: "patrick",
        last: "coleman"
      },
      location: {
        city: "stockton",
        state: "minnesota",
        zip: "10532"
      },
      email: "patrick.coleman45@example.com",
      username: "ticklishostrich48",
      password: "darkknight55",
      salt: ">DyBf9aih",
      md5: "5d6bf4508070fba41e2d602c847cdbd9",
      sha1: "19e5b0b59e6c86dbf370c431a7edb2aa4f1420a6",
      sha256: "9434e04d307839d9b6411254007072412c11f7e6b5d8fd848e56fe5f0c660a04"
    },
    version: "0.4"
  }]
}
```

How can I access data by key value? 
I would do something like:

```
Results["results"]["version"]
Results["results"]["user"]["name"]["first"]
```

Thanks in advance, Best regards, Christian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original approach will work, if you modify it a little bit:

```
// Simple POST request
using (System.Net.WebClient wb = new System.Net.WebClient())
{
    // Random user data API - http://randomuser.me/
    string url = "http://api.randomuser.me/";

    var data = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();
    var responseStringJson = Encoding.Default.GetString(wb.UploadValues(url, "POST", data));

    var jsSerializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    var results = jsSerializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(responseStringJson);

    // Note that the following works, because Console.WriteLine
    // automatically formats those objects to a string. If you want
    // to use these anywhere else, you will have to cast/convert the
    // values every time you access them.
    Console.WriteLine(results["results"][0]["version"]);
    Console.WriteLine(results["results"][0]["user"]["name"]["first"]);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I would, however, suggest that you create some strongly typed classes which you then use in your project. For example, if you put your API url into http://json2csharp.com/ and add those classes to your project, the code for reading the data would look a bit different:

```
// Simple POST request
using (System.Net.WebClient wb = new System.Net.WebClient())
{
    // Random user data API - http://randomuser.me/
    string url = "http://api.randomuser.me/";

    var data = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();
    var responseStringJson = Encoding.Default.GetString(wb.UploadValues(url, "POST", data));

    var jsSerializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    var results = jsSerializer.Deserialize<RootObject>(responseStringJson);

    Console.WriteLine(results.results[0].version);
    Console.WriteLine(results.results[0].user.name.first);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The big advantages are that you can add type conversion to the proxy classes, without having to do that every time you access a value from the dictionary, and that you get full IDE and compiler support for the objects' properties (less typos):

Comment: Thanks Hangy. I used typed classes that you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

If the value of each key is a dictionary too, then you must specify that in the declaration. Not sure if the deserializer you're using supports it but give it a try.

```cs
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>>
```

I wouldn't advice trying retrieve a full object immediately though, this might work for a single nested dictionary, but there are probably complexity limits. Its best to iterate over each `KeyValuePair` in the dictionary, if the value is a dictionary type, then cast is as such and handle it individually. This way the deserializer doesn't have to assume that all values are a dictionary by definition.

Comment: The value of each key is not a dictionary too. I update my post with an JSON data example.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I access data by key value? I would do something like:
>   `Results["results"]["user"]["name"]["first"]`

<strike>This syntax is not possible in C#, since variables are strongly typed.</strike>
Actually, as hangy explained, this *is* possible with the new dynamic keyword in .net 4.0, which you already used in your question. 
According to [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9495155/145999), all you need to do is use [System.Web.Helpers.Json.Decode()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg538324(v=vs.111).aspx) to deserialize your Json object, it will return a `dynamic` object, that you should be able to access somewhat like this: `Results.results.user.name.first`

---

Without the use of net 4.0 dynamic casting, you could also write a function like this:

```
 Results.GetValue("results","user","name","first");
```

You can write this method as an [extension method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/403556/145999) for Dictionary:

```
public static class JsonNestedDictionaryExtensions
{
    public static Object GetValue(this Dictionary<String,Object> dict, params string[] keys)
    {
        Object dictObject = dict;
        String lastKey = "";
        foreach (string key in keys)
        {
             if (!dictObject is Dictionary<String,Object>)
                 throw new ArgumentException(key+ " cannot be accessed because "+lastKey+" is not a dictionary");
             dict = (Dictionary<String,Object>) dictObject;

             dictObject = dict["key"];
             lastKey = key;
        }

        return dictObject;
    }
}
```

Comment: It does work if they just use the object as `dynamic` instead of casting it to `Dictionary<string, object>`. But it's not really a nice way to work with that data. ;)

Comment: Thanks, I totally forgot about that new feature.