# Add method to a class from another project

Tags: c#, extension-methods

Is it possible to add a method to a class from another project?

I have a class:

```
namespace ProjectLibrary
{
    public class ClassA
    {
        // some methods
    }
}
```

I want to add a method to save my object in a file, but I don't want to add this method in my project `ProjectLibrary` because I don't want to add reference to System.IO (I want to use this project for android application and PC application).

Is there a possibility to add a method `SaveToFile()` usable only in another project? Or create an abstract method in ClassA but define it in other project.

Like this :

```
using ProjectLibrary;
namespace ProjectOnPC
{
    void methodExample()
    {
        ClassA obj = new ClassA();
        // do something
        obj.SaveToFile();// => available only in namespace ProjectOnPC
    }
}
```

Thank you for help

Comment: You might have bennefits with Conditional compiling

Comment: Take a look at extension methods.

Comment: Extension method or inherit the class maybe?

Comment: you could create an extension method

Comment: Your declaration `public ClassA` is not valid C#. But as the other comments say, inheritance and extension method are good options -- or even just a method that takes ClassA as a parameter. (Which is all an extension method boils down to anyway.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing You are looking for is called `Extension method`:

- [DotNetPerls](https://www.dotnetperls.com/extension)
- [MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-Gb/library/bb383977.aspx)
- [What are Extension Methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403539/what-are-extension-methods)

Code for base class:

```
namespace ProjectLibrary
{
    public ClassA
    {
        // some methods
    }
}
```

Extension method:

```
using ProjectLibrary;
namespace ProjectOnPC
{
    void SaveToFile(this ClassA Obj, string Path)
    {
        //Implementation of saving Obj to Path
    }
}
```

Calling in Your program:

```
using ProjectLibrary;
using ProjectOnPc; //if You won't include this, You cannot use ext. method

public void Main(string[] args)
{
    ClassA mObj = new ClassA();
    mObj.SaveToFile("c:\\MyFile.xml");
}
```

Comment: Didn,'t know that, thank you for answer and documentation.

Answer (score 3):

You can use extension methods.

Example:

```
namespace ProjectOnPC
{
    public static void SaveToFile(this Class myClass)
    {
      //Save to file.
    }
}
```

Comment: You missed the class declaration.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an **extension method** for this purpose.

Here's an example.
In your ProjectOnPc namespace create a class like this:

```
public static class ClassAExtension
{
    public static void SaveToFile(this ClassA obj)
    {
        // write your saving logic here.
        // obj will represent your current instance of ClassA on which you're invoking the method.
        SaveObject(obj).
    }
}
```

You can learn more about extension methods here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx