# How to cast DataTable to CustomDataTable?

Tags: c#, inheritance, casting

I wrote a class `CustomDataTable` that inherits `DataTable` but adds the function `ToHtml()`

## CustomDataTable

```
public static CustomDataTable : DataTable {
   public Table ToHtml() {
       Table tbl;
       /*
            logic for converting each row in the DataTable to HTML TableRow
       */
       return tbl;
   }
}
```

Usage:

```
public static CustomDataTable getTable(String sql) {
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection_string);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql,con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    return (CustomDataTable)ds.Tables[0];   // this line triggers the exception
        // Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataTable' to type 'MyProject.CustomDataTable'

}
```

Why did the cast fail?

Comment: You can't cast to a more derived type.

Comment: You have to create a Copy method where you read the DataTable and insert data cell by cell into the CustomDataTable, there's no automatic relation between them otherwise to do the typecasting

Comment: @MrinalKamboj is there a way to extend the class `DataTable` so that it can perform the new method?

Comment: @Ahmad extension method. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40802711/3181933). The `static` class and `static` method are important.

Comment: @Ahmad extending shall not be an issue, but filling would pose the same challenge since DataAdapter doesn't know about the `CustomDataTable`

Comment: Easier way would be instead of extending aggregate the DataTable and then use it in the Custom method

Comment: Write it as an extension method instead if you want to add functionality to a base class, otherwise you need to create the original object as an instance of your new type.

Comment: Can you instead try the following `public int Fill(DataTable dataTable)` method of the `SqlDataAdapter`, whic shall be able to take the instance of the `CustomDataTable` and thus fill the data into it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why did the cast fail?

Because it's invalid. `ds.Tables[0]` returns a `DataTable` and nothing else and you can't cast a `DataTable` to a more derived type like `CustomDataTable`.

Instead of creating a derived class, you could consider creating an [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) that extends `DataTable` with a `ToHtml()` method:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public Table ToHtml(this DataTable dt)
    {
        /*
             logic for converting each row in the DataTable to HTML TableRow
        */
    }
}
```

You could then call this one on any `DataTable` without casting, e.g.:

```
var htmlTable = ds.Tables[0].ToHtml();
```