# Pasted code over to another class and it doesnt work?

Tags: c#

I have a piece of code

```
string phoneMobileW = null;
string phoneMobileP = null;
string phoneMain = null;
string phoneWork = null;
string phoneHome = null;

if (coreData.ListOfAddress_0006 != null && coreData.ListOfAddress_0006.Count() > 0)
{
    var phoneqry = from list in coreData.ListOfAddress_0006
        .Where(a => a.Subtype.ID == "1")
        .OrderByDescending(a => a.StartDate)
        .Take(1)
        .Where(p => p.ListOfPhoneNumber_0006 != null)
        .SelectMany(p => p.ListOfPhoneNumber_0006)
        select list;

    if (phoneqry != null)
    {
        var phoneList = phoneqry.ToList();
        phoneMobileW = phoneList
            .Where(q => q.NumberType.ID == "MOBW")
            .Select(q => q.Number)
            .LastOrDefault();
    }
}
```

The phone numbers are contained inside the address. If the address is not empty get the last phone number. However I have coped and pasted this piece of code over to another class it and it longer works.
[image]

So where it works you can see the 'var' for phoneqry is interface System.Collections.Generic.Ienumerable

As I said I have copied it over to another class which is a unit testing class.
I am trying to populate the phone number.

When I hold the cursor over var, nothing appears to show me what object it is(is this because its in a unitTest class?)

anyway the error I get is for .Where in `var phoneqry = from list in coreData.ListOfAddress_0006.Where`

> Error 4   'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) D:\MartinsCode\New folder\Trunk\BusinessLogic\SapEai.UnitTest\AdUnitTest.cs 166 73  RFS.BusinessLogic.SapEai.UnitTest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Where` is a Linq extension method, you need to add this at the top of your file:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Alternatively, you can click on `Where` and press Ctrl+. on your keyboard, and it will prompt you to include the using for the System.Linq namespace.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403539/what-are-extension-methods) for more information on what extension methods are.

Comment: thank You that worked. I did previously right click on the object and choose resolve, i must have chose the wrong ref tho. thank you